# How to disable backBarButtonItem?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

During network requests, I like to disable (deactivate + grey out) every view on my current view controller. The only view I just cannot disable is the back bar button:

```
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems?.forEach { $0.isEnabled = !isVisible }

navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = !isVisible

navigationController?.navigationBar.backItem?.backBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = !isVisible
```

Any ideas?

Comment: use `navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true` or `navigationController?.navigationBar.userInteractionEnabled = false`

Comment: Unfortunately, the answers in the post above also don't solve the problem. `hidesBackButton` will permantly set the button invisible, which is not what I want. `userInteractionEnabled` on navigationBar does not work on iOS 10 and up. Looks like there is no working solution as of now.

Comment: use this line 
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true

Comment: That's what the first comment said already. Firstly, this will hide the button completely, which is not what I want. Secondly, this will not toggle properly because setting this property doesn't prompt the navigation bar to update its status.